# Python Selenium page cannot save source code encode error

Tags: python, selenium, unicode

I am trying to save source code with Selenium into .txt, but the .txt file stays empty.

When I tryed to print the source code with command:

```
htmlcode = driver.page_source
(driver.page_source).encode('utf-8'))
print(htmlcode)
```

It will print the source code but then it kills the script with error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 16329: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that saves to file ?

Comment: I used the script below, but this wont work because of the encode error i gues. 
site=browser.open(link)
fileobjj = open("output.txt","wb")
fileobjj.write(site.read())
fileobjj.close()

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! After 3 hours searching ':-)

```
html = driver.page_source
f = open('savepage.html', 'w')
f.write(html.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```